# Return DataTable from a Function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a Function which returns DataTable Like this (if there are Rows)...

```
Protected Function getAideData() As DataTable

    Dim dt As DataTable = DAL.ReturnData("select * from pg_PersonalInfo P Left Join pg_employeeInterview E on E.sesID = P.sesID ")
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Return dt
    End If

End Function
```

Then later in my page I accress it like this:

```
Dim d as datatable = getAideData
```

Here is my problem: If I have Data in Datatable then I have no problem, however if I dont have any data returned from my method then there is a issue.

I guess my question is, if I have a Function and that cannot return a datatable (no rows), then what should I return from my function? So i can handle the data properly later in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess my question is, if I have a Function and that cannot return a
>   datatable (no rows), then what should I return from my function?

Return Nothing

```
Protected Function getAideData() As DataTable

    Dim dt As DataTable = DAL.ReturnData("select * from pg_PersonalInfo P Left Join pg_employeeInterview E on E.sesID = P.sesID ")
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Return dt
    End If
    Return Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: and when I call the Function, would it throw any error? Dim d as datatable = getAideData

Comment: @highwingers, not it shouldn't. It will be assigned null/nothing

Comment: @highwingers, but later you should check for null, before invoking any of its instance members to avoid NRE

Answer (score 0):

```
Function GetDataTable(ByVal qry As String) As DataTable
        Dim DbCon As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Try
            Dim ConStr As String
            ConStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnCMSTrend").ToString()
            DbCon.ConnectionString = ConStr
            DbCon.Open()
            Dim queryString As String = qry
            Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, ConStr)
            Dim res As DataSet = New DataSet
            adapter.Fill(res)
            DbCon.Close()
            GetCMSTrend = res.Tables(0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            DbCon.Close()
        End Try
    End Function
```

'Note That you need to add the connection string in the appsettings file. In the above case ConnCMSTrend is the database connection string.